# How to reference to .desktop file? (installed in /opt) in a dynamic quicklist?

Tags: application-development, quickly, quicklists, unity

I'm trying to create a dynamic quicklist for an application I'm developing in quickly.

This is the line of code I use to try and connect to the .desktop file:

```
self.launcher = Unity.LauncherEntry.get_for_desktop_id("my-app.desktop")
```

For testing purposes, I've found that when using `quickly run` I should copy the .desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications`. When I do this, the quicklist shows up correctly.

However, when packaging my app using `quickly package --extras`, and installing this package, I get a launcher without quicklist.

Does this have something to do with my app being installed in `/opt`? Meaning my desktop file is located somewhere else?
Should I use another reference to the desktop file?

EDIT:

I've tried to find the .desktop file. But I can't seem to locate it.. Does this mean I should generate one myself? and that I should link to that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when you package with the `--extras` parameter, the .desktop file gets a prefix.
So I needed to reference to the desktop file like this:

```
self.launcher = Unity.LauncherEntry.get_for_desktop_id("extras-my-app.desktop")
```

Comment: I had a similar question regarding the use of the get_for_desktop_id() command. Should it be extras-*.desktop or just *.desktop? I stumbled across the ARB Guidelines and they make it pretty clear that it should be extras-*.desktop. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/Review/Guidelines